# Why am I getting the incompatible type for the first method?

Tags: java, arraylist

The goal here is to have this method return an ArrayList of Strings with the values of an object in a chosen line "n" in the table.

public ArrayList getLine(int line);

Here's what I have:

```
public ArrayList<String> getLine(int line) {
       ArrayList<String> nLine = new ArrayList<String>();
int first = 0;
int last =0;
for(int i = first; i<= last; i++) { 
 nLine.add(players.get(i).getAttributes());
}
return nLine;
    }
```

I am getting the incompatible type: ArrayList cannot be converted to String. There also needs to be another method.
public ArrayList<ArrayList> getLines(int firstLine, int lastLine);

This methods used the getLine( ) method. It gets a set of lines (each one of them an array of Strings) from getLine( int n) and adds them to an array of arrays. It returns this array of arrays. The code for this method seems to be working:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getLines(int firstLine, int lastLine) {
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listLines = new ArrayList<>();
        int first = 0;
        int last = 0;
        for (int i = first; i<= last; i++) {
            listLines.add(players.get(i).getAttributeNames());
        }
        return listLines;    }
```

Why am I getting the incompatible type for the first method?

Comment: What is `getAttributes()` and what is `getAttributeNames()`? Also `first` and `last` are both `0`. This code seems specious.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent your code properly (your IDE can do it). It makes a great difference to people’s willingness to read your code to see whether anything is wrong.

Comment: You will probably want to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Though the code is evidently quite strange, the problem is that your `players.get(i).getAttributes()`  returns a list of strings but not a string. Therefore, you can’t add it as a new element to your list of strings nList.